# Value of tooltip replaced for last foreach value

Tags: c#

I have an event to get Tooltip text in column chart like:

```
empChart.GetToolTipText += empChart_GetToolTipText;
```

then method is like:

```
private void empChart_GetToolTipText(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e )
{
    if (e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
    {
        Chart senderChart = (Chart)sender;
        var series = senderChart.Series;
        var points = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points;

        foreach (var s in series)
        {
            var finalString = s.LegendToolTip.Replace("\r", "");
            string[] tooltipstring = finalString.Split('\n');

            string progresstoBackCheckString = string.Join("\n", tooltipstring.Where(x => x.Contains("progress to backcheck")));
            string backcheckToCorrectionsString = string.Join("\n", tooltipstring.Where(x => x.Contains("backcheck to corrections")));
            string correctionsToCompletedString = string.Join("\n", tooltipstring.Where(x => x.Contains("corrections to completed")));
            string progressToCompletedString = string.Join("\n", tooltipstring.Where(x => x.Contains("progress to completed")));

            int i = e.HitTestResult.PointIndex;

            DataPoint dp = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points[i];

            switch (dp.AxisLabel)
            {
                case "Progress to Back Check":
                    e.Text = $"{progresstoBackCheckString}";
                    break;
                case "Back Check to Corrections":
                    e.Text = $"{backcheckToCorrectionsString}";
                    break;
                case "Corrections to Completed":
                    e.Text = $"{correctionsToCompletedString}";
                    break;
                case "Progress to Completed":
                    e.Text = $"{progressToCompletedString}";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment I receive two series, so I want to assign one different tooltip with his current `s.LegendToolTip`  at each serie. Problem is that two series replace value of first serie, so both series have same ToolTipText. What can I do to set tooltip of each serie depending of their received `s.LegendToolTip`?

there is no way to know what serie I hover? in `GetToolTipText` event? Regards

Comment: You can simply write: `empChart.GetToolTipText += empChart_GetToolTipText;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Comment: `$"{somestring}"` why? Just use `somestring`.

Comment: As I told you in a post you deleted, you can have a separate tooltip for each series. It will appear when hovering over it.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToolTipEventArgs e` have a property `HitTestResult` providing detailed information on the chart element `GetToolTipText` event was raised for. The [HitTestResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.hittestresult?view=netframework-4.7.2) has a `Series` property which in turn has a `Name` property which you could test.

```
if (e.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPointLabel) {
    switch (e.HitTestResult.Series.Name)
    {
        case "My series 1 name":
            ...
            break;
        case "My series 2 name":
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

You will have to make tests to see what exactly the `ToolTipEventArgs` contains when hovering over different parts of the chart.

In case this is not possible (because the name is not known), test like this

```
if (empChart.Series[0] == e.HitTestResult.Series) {
   // First series
}
```

But I guess that the chart object automatically assigns a default series name like "`Series 1`". (Not tested). Use the debugger to check it.

Comment: problem is my serie is dynamic, so I don't know what is the current series Name, try to use in foreach like `foreach(var bb in e.HitTestResult.Series.Name)
                    {}` but I can't assign e.Text of that series there because bb.Text doesn't exist

Comment: there is no way to know what serie I hover?

Comment: You could probably do something like `if (empChart.Series[0] == e.HitTestResult.Series) { ... }` by just testing for reference equality.

Comment: Finally I solve issuem that e.HitTestResult.Series is the key to solve that. I posted answer

Answer (score 0):

To do that I create a model then I search for hitted or hover bar on chart:

```
  if (e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
            {
                Chart senderChart = (Chart)sender;
                var series = senderChart.Series;
                var points = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points;

                //e.HitTestResult.Series.
                var legendTip = series.Select(x => new
                {
                    x.LegendToolTip,
                    x.Name
                }).ToList();

                List<TooltipTextModel> tooltipModel = new List<TooltipTextModel>();
                foreach (var lt in legendTip)
                {
                TooltipTextModel assignTooltip = new TooltipTextModel();
                    var finalString = lt.LegendToolTip.Replace("\r", "");
                    string[] tooltipstring = finalString.Split('\n');

                    var progresstoBackCheckString = string.Join("\n", tooltipstring.Where(x => x.Contains("progress to backcheck")));
                    var backcheckToCorrectionsString = string.Join("\n", tooltipstring.Where(x => x.Contains("backcheck to corrections")));
                    var correctionsToCompletedString = string.Join("\n", tooltipstring.Where(x => x.Contains("corrections to completed")));
                    var progressToCompletedString = string.Join("\n", tooltipstring.Where(x => x.Contains("progress to completed")));

                    assignTooltip.ProgresstoBackCheckString = progresstoBackCheckString;
                    assignTooltip.BackcheckToCorrectionsString = backcheckToCorrectionsString;
                    assignTooltip.CorrectionsToCompletedString = correctionsToCompletedString;
                    assignTooltip.ProgressToCompletedString = progressToCompletedString;
                    assignTooltip.SerieName = lt.Name;
                    tooltipModel.Add(assignTooltip);
                    }

                var hitSerie = e.HitTestResult.Series.Name.ToString();

                foreach (var tt in tooltipModel.Where(x=>x.SerieName == hitSerie))
                {
                    int i = e.HitTestResult.PointIndex;
                    var chartSerie = empChart.Series[e.HitTestResult.Series.Name].Name.ToString();

                        DataPoint dp = e.HitTestResult.Series.Points[i];

                        switch (dp.AxisLabel)
                        {
                            case "Progress to Back Check":
                                e.Text = $"{tt.ProgresstoBackCheckString}";
                                break;
                            case "Back Check to Corrections":
                                e.Text = $"{tt.BackcheckToCorrectionsString}";
                                break;
                            case "Corrections to Completed":
                                e.Text = $"{tt.CorrectionsToCompletedString}";
                                break;
                            case "Progress to Completed":
                                e.Text = $"{tt.ProgressToCompletedString}";
                                break;
                    }
                }
            }
```